# How to read environment variable inside shell file

Tags: shell, tcl, environment-variables

i have a tcl file and defining my environment variable inside that file. something like below

```
set env(ET_PINASSIGN_SCRIPT) $ET_PINASSIGN_SCRIPT
```

where `$ET_PINASSIGN_SCRIPT` variable will have a user incoming input value. Now I need to read this env variable in a shell file (`#!/bin/ksh`
). This is what i am trying and not working

```
$env ET_PINASSIGN_SCRIPT .
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is not possible. A program which is running, eg. your script, receives a *duplicate* of the environment, and can modify it. But when the program stops running, it disappears, together with its environment and changes.

There are few direct methods to communicate 'from the dead' process. You could create a temporary file, or return simple integers from the exit code.

Another way, would be to run the other program concurrently in a way that they share the same environment,

More info on the environment:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

Edit: I feel I wasn't clear enough: I just wanted to point out that programming that modifies the environment for other programs is 'extreme' (i.e. dangerous) programming. All kind of tricks can be done which can have lasting influences on the use of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to make the Tcl code write a shell script to set the variable to standard out (with `puts`) and to then do:

```
eval `tclsh yourscript.tcl`
```

in your shell.

---

The Tcl code would probably be something like:

```
puts "ET_PINASSIGN_SCRIPT='$ET_PINASSIGN_SCRIPT'"
```

except you'll have to worry about any embedded `'` characters, so might do…

```
puts "ET_PINASSIGN_SCRIPT='[string map {' '\\''} $ET_PINASSIGN_SCRIPT]'"
```